# How to retrieve single image from database when there are multiple images in database using PHP?

Tags: php

The query below is  retrieving all images of `userid` 85, how to retrieve single image of user 85.

```
SELECT link FROM `images` WHERE uid='85';
```

Comment: Without knowing your db structure, there is no chance to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Which image do you want exaclty from all set of user images? If is just one of them, use `LIMIT 0,1` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT in your query like this

```
SELECT link FROM images WHERE uid='85' LIMIT 0,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your database schema but maybe add a limit to your request

```
SELECT link FROM images WHERE uid='85' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) in your query like @Vivek and @Antoine mentioned.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT link FROM images WHERE uid='85' LIMIT 0,1;
```

With `LIMIT $offset,$limit` have to set a `$limit` and you can set a optional `$offset`

So the following query will start at row 6 (because `$offset` is 5) and will return 10 rows (because `$limit` is 10)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

It is possible to just use the `$limit` if you want to return the first 10 entries:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 10;  # Retrieve first 10 rows
```

If you are using limit for paging for example, have in mind to use `ORDER BY` to retrieve a consistent result. Otherwise it could be possible that another query mixes up your result in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT link FROM `images` WHERE uid='85' LIMIT 1;
```